# ¿Cuál es la diferencia en el significado del presente y pretérito perfecto simple del subjuntivo en combinación con el futuro?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, subjuntivo

Considere estas dos frases:

> **Aunque no estudie, haré el examen.**
>
> **Aunque no haya estudiado, haré el examen.**

Mi primera lengua es el inglés, pero ya sé mucho español, aunque todavía me falta entender bien los temas avanzados como estos. Yo pregunté a mi maestra (de español) y ella me explicó, pero no entendí bien.

Estoy buscando una explicación detallada de las diferencias entre las dos frases y, también en general, cómo usar las dos diferentes formaciones de subjuntivo con futuro.

Yo sé que es muy difícil explicar el subjuntivo, especialmente a alguien que habla inglés, porque no existe el subjuntivo en ese idioma. La respuesta podría ser en inglés o español, yo puedo leer bien los dos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, no está en cuestión el subjuntivo, sino el aspecto.

Cuando dices *haya estudiado*, la interpretación es que cualquier estudio que hayas hecho habría ocurrido antes del momento de la oración. Es algo que escucharás, por ejemplo, cuando ya viene el examen pronto y se supone que no queda tiempo para estudiar más.

Ya que queda casi completamente en desuso el futuro del subjuntivo, *estudie* tiene dos interpretaciones temporales — del presente y del futuro. En este caso, significa los estudios que quizás estés haciendo o los que podrás realizar en el futuro.

Quizás estarás ahora preguntando si hay alguna forma de representar el futuro perfecto (los estudios que realices antes del examen, sin respecto a ahora), ya que *estudie* contempla el presente y el futuro en el español moderno. En este caso, a menos que quieras decir algo performal como *hubiere estudiado*, tanto como *estudie* es el sustituto moderno de *estudiare*, lo es *haya estudiado* de *hubiere estudiado*.

¿Como podemos distinguir el uso, entonces, entre el *haya estudiado* que representa solo los estudios de antes de ahora, y el *haya estudiado* que representa todos los que vienen antes del examen? Desafortunadamente, la respuesta es un sencillo «contexto».

Answer (score 3):

As you are not satisfied with the traditional explanation, let me try to give one that is more visual:

Lets define four moments in time :

- t0: when the sentence is said
- t1: time the sentence is referring to
- ts: study period
- te: exam period

So your first construction ('estudie') can mean the orders:

- t0->t1->ts->te or
- t0->ts->t1->te

And the second ('haya estudiado') can mean:

- t0->ts->t1->te or
- ts->t0->t1->te

You can see that in one case both sentences are equivalent (when the sentence is said before the study period and refers to the moment between the study period and the exam) but if you want to convey any of the other meanings you must use the correct one.

Hope it helps